# Why equals() is there is Comparator but not in Comparable interface in Java

Tags: java

equals() method is there in Comparator interface, but it is not present in Comparable interface. Why? Also, As per the contract between equals() and hashcode(), both must be overridden, it is not the case in Comparator. Why ? Can anyone help me to understand the concept behind it.

Comment: `Comparator` solves another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> equals() method is there in Comparator interface, but it is not present in Comparable interface. Why?

Comparator.equals(...) is for testing if an object is equal *to this comparator*; it's *not* for testing whether two comparable objects are equals. (That's why it takes a single `Object`, not two `T`-s.) So just because Comparator declares it, doesn't mean there's any reason for Comparable to declare it.

That said, it's still worth asking why Comparator declares it, since Comparator (like every type) is already a subtype of Object. The reason for that is simply that Comparator wants to impose some extra requirements on equals(...), so it needs to supply specific Javadoc. (Specifically, it requires that two comparators never be considered equal unless they implement the same ordering. Implementations of Comparator can satisfy this requirement by just using the equals(...) from Object, or by defining a custom equals(...) that's more precise.)

> Also, As per the contract between equals() and hashcode(), both must be overridden, it is not the case in Comparator.

Comparator doesn't actually "override" equals(...). Implementors of Comparator still inherit Object.equals(...), unless they override it.

Since Comparator is not providing an actual implementation of equals() — it just specifies some additional requirements — it doesn't need to say anything special about hashCode(). The general contract of hashCode(), and the relationship of hashCode() to equals(), still applies.

Answer (score 1):

A class implementing Comparable already has an equals method inherited from Object, and Comparable imposes no extra constraints on equals().

Comparator requires that, for MyComparatorType.equals(Comparator other) to return true, both my comparator and the other comparator impose the same ordering. This allows for some performance improvements and optimizations, and will likely cause a runtime exception at some point down the line if this special contract is violated.

The relevant lines from [the Comparator javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this comparator. This method must obey the general contract of Object.equals(Object).
>
> Additionally, this method can return true only if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator. Thus, comp1.equals(comp2) implies that sgn(comp1.compare(o1, o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2)) for every object reference o1 and o2.
>
> Note that it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object). However, overriding this method may, in some cases, improve performance by allowing programs to determine that two distinct comparators impose the same order.

So Comparator *should* follow the same contract as any other thing implementing Object.equals(Object), which includes correct hashCode() behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`equals(Object obj)` is present in all classes. It comes from `Object` class.

In `Comparator` interface, `equals(Object obj)` declaration is added to override the related javadoc in order that clients be aware of the interest to override `equals()` method for **this** class. It's a hint.

Javadoc of `equals(Object obj)` in Comparator  :

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this comparator.
>   This method must obey the general contract of Object.equals(Object).
>   Additionally, this method can return true only if the specified object
>   is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this
>   comparator. Thus, comp1.equals(comp2) implies that
>   sgn(comp1.compare(o1, o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2)) for every
>   object reference o1 and o2.
>
> Note that it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object).
>   However, overriding this method may, in some cases, improve
>   performance by allowing programs to determine that two distinct
>   comparators impose the same order.

What is the point ?
imagine you must call several times the `Collections.sort()` method with different comparators. If two comparators are equals() and you applied already one comparator, you should not apply the second comparator since it will have no effect. As said, it's a hint.

In `Comparable`, JDK developers don't judge useful to add any information about `equals` method overriding. Object's `equals(Object obj)` Javadoc should so be enough.